# Customizing my account page in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I customize the my account page in woocommerce, I can edit right side section by creating my_account.php inside my account folder in woocommerce. But In left side it is showing "Define your 'My Account' navigation Apperance > Menus", 
After seeing this I tried to create menu called "My account", but there was no theme location existing, so I create a theme location called "my account menu". And I assign "my account" menu with theme location "my account menu".

I don't know how to connect this menu to my account page in woocommerce, the page again showing same "Define your 'My Account' navigation Apperance > Menus".

Comment: 2 days am trying to find a solution, but no use. and one important point am using theme flatsome with extension nasmedia for wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Try Appearance>Menus>Custom Links

Otherwise:

Is the theme you are trying to edit a pre-built theme?
Is the platform up-to-date or outdated (sometimes updates/bugs can alter functionality of pre existing code)?
Sometimes there are errors in the theme build, as I have seen. In such a case, I would recommend reaching out to the theme developer(s) as they can usually help the best in this situation. If not, check back. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, flatsome is an existing theme, but something happend to my code structure, I dont know.

Comment: Can you please tell me little bit more about this

Comment: We won't know anything about the code without seeing it. But keep in mind that files are are associated with other background theme files. If none of these solutions worked (including those posted below) I would contact your theme developer. In my case, they are happy to help. I messed a lot of things up in a pre existing theme and the Dev fixed it for me which I gladly gave him a donation and a positive review.

Answer (score 0):

Call menu by menu name instead of theme_location

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Main Menu' ) ); ?>
```